# how do I return a value from a worker for a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, worker

I have a function that spawns a worker

```
function fetchFile(mes) {

    const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    worker.postMessage(mes);

    //somehow return the message returned by the worker
}
```

worker.js:

```
self.onmessage = function (msg) {
    //some complex calculations
}
```

and I want to return the value calculated by the worker for the function

is there a way to do this?

Comment: You definitely can't synchronously return the worker's message, since it doesn't exist yet. Do you want to return a promise that eventually resolves to the message?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, that would work

Comment: The [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) has several examples. Which of these have you tried? If you want to use Promises, see [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](/q/22519784/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worker:

```js
self.addEventListener("message", (msg) => {
  // Some complex calculations.
  postMessage(workerResult);
});
```

In the main app:

```js
const worker = new Worker("worker.js");

worker.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
  result.textContent = e.data;
  console.log("Message received from worker");
});
worker.postMessage(mes);
```

Comment: how would you embed it into a function ?

Comment: @notabot What do you mean by that? Why does the event listener need to be embedded into a function?

Comment: @SebastianSimon so It would be easy to spawn workers and acquire results without blocking the main thread; also how would you implement a promise as the sources provided does not necessary provide an example

Comment: @notabot Just wrap this code in a Promise executor, pass it to a Promise constructor and return it from some function (e.g. `const spawnWorker = (mes) => new Promise((resolve) => {`…`})`). Call `resolve` in the `message` event listener. This is all mentioned in the documentation and the linked Q&A. Don’t use `onmessage`, though — this approach is very outdated. Use `worker.addEventListener("message", (e) => {`…`})` instead.